# Force USB Host Mode

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, usb-host-mode

I am trying to use an USB-serial device that has USB-A connector via USB OTG.
How do I "force USB host mode" so I can use USB-A to USB-C cable instead of using OTG adapter?

OTG works fine with other devices such as sd-card to type c adapter

Rooted Pixel 1 with Android 10

Comment: AFAIK for device with USB-C port there is no difference between an USB-A to USB-C cable to an OTG adapter. OTG adapters were necessary for Micro-USB ports.

Comment: I get no power just from USB-A to USB-C cable. isn't there physical resistor inside otg adapter so device can know the mode?

Comment: Usually the USB connection can be switched to "this device controls USB connection" (which means OTG mode). A lot of people are complaining about OTG problems with Pixel phones, not sure what the reason ist. What USB device do you want to connect to your phone? How much power does it require?

Comment: I think setting you mentioned isn't related. "usb controlled by this device" mode is enabled when connected to pc, if that's the OTG mode pc shouldn't be able to communicate since pc is ALWAYS the master. it's a regular serial device. requires 5v. I also powered it externally but still not detected as client device. OTG works fine with other devices such as sd-card to type c adapter

Comment: If it just does not works with this device then most likely the device type is not supported. I would try to connect the device to a Linux machine and check what driver(s) are used. Then check if the used Android kernel also contains this driver. In the end you may need a custom kernel(module) to make the device work. May be custom ROMs like LineageOS already has the correct drivers included. It may be worth a try.

Comment: usb-devices command shows Driver=(none). to get the device working it should draw power from phone in the first place but I'm not getting any power because phone isn't aware that I'm connecting it to slave device, that's what the resistor is supposed to do.

Comment: But you wrote that other USB devices work if you connect it to your phone. Therefore I don't think that power is the problem (as long as the serial adapter is strictly USB compliant). As I wrote on USB-C there is no extra PIN for OTG and therefore no resistor.

Comment: exactly, there is no power problem on other device. so how come I don't get power on this one if every usb cable is same?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291413/usb-c-to-usb-a-pinout
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/435612/usb-2-0-cable-to-usb-c-output

Comment: AFAIR By default USB devices are allowed to draw only 0,1 A. Only after the device has establishes the communication with the port (which requires a proper driver) more power can be drawn. Hence I would assume that because of the missing driver the device is not allowed to draw the power it needs.

Answer (score 0):

To force your device into USB host mode, try connecting your USB-serial device via USB hub.
Connecting a USB hub to your OTG adapter sets it automatically as host.